# Delete rows based on list of row numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of row numbers that I need to keep.  All other rows need deleted.

This macro deletes entire rows based on row numbers in a list.  It works exactly as intended.

How can it be altered to delete all rows EXCEPT those rows on the list?

```
Dim deleteRows As Range
Dim data() As Variant
Dim i As Double

Dim SourceWks As Worksheet
Dim oldWks As Worksheet

Set SourceWks = Sheets("TBDws")
Set oldWks = Sheets("TBDsamples")

    With SourceWks
        data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
    End With

    Set deleteRows = oldWks.Rows(data(1, 1))

    For i = 2 To UBound(data, 1)

        Set deleteRows = Union(deleteRows, oldWks.Rows(data(i, 1)))

    Next i

    deleteRows.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the example data from the `SourceWks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will delete all the rows on the sheet `TBDsamples` that aren't listed in column A on `TBDws`

```
Sub DeleteThings()
Dim SourceWks As Worksheet
Dim oldWks As Worksheet
Dim deleteRange As Range
Dim arrRows() As Variant
Dim Res As Variant
Dim I As Long

    Set SourceWks = Sheets("TBDws")
    Set oldWks = Sheets("TBDsamples")

    With SourceWks
        arrRows = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))
    End With

    For I = 1 To oldWks.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Res = Application.Match(I, arrRows, 0)
        If IsError(Res) Then
            If deleteRange Is Nothing Then
                Set deleteRange = oldWks.Rows(I)
            Else
                Set deleteRange = Union(deleteRange, oldWks.Rows(I))
            End If
        End If

    Next I

    deleteRange.Delete Shift:=xlUp

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that `Application.Match` works many times faster on a range than on an array i.e. `Dim data As Range: Set data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown))` (use a better variable name though).

Comment: Didn't know that.:)

Comment: One additional question:  Although this code works when there are only 11 rows on the TBDsamples worksheet, I will need that number to be variable depending on the size of my data.  When I change the line 'For i = 11' to use the variable given above, the code no longer works correctly.

Comment: Sorry, that's kind of a typo - I'll edit the answer later to fix it.

Comment: Please let me know when you have updated.  I'd like to change my code ASAP.  Thanks!

Comment: I've update the code.